# Does "going Spare" really relate to Austin Osman Spare?

Tags: meaning

Back in 2013 'Urbycoz' [asked why 'Go Spare' meant 'Getting Angry'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118702/why-does-go-spare-mean-get-angry) and this elicited a number of interesting replies. Coming late to the party I have just read this and was puzzled because I had always assumed that 'going spare' meant 'going crazy', or 'going mad' and have used it as such. To this extent I am more in tune with [user68709's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/157209/18696) that it was derived from a reference to Austin Osman Spare, (1886-1956) the English illustrator and artist who was certainly, er, unusual.

> I've sometimes wondered if it might not relate to Austin Osman Spare, the WW1 War artist. He showed enormous talent and promise before the War, but many thought he 'went a bit odd' afterwards, and he dropped out of sight and was almost unknown by his death in 1955. He regained some popularity in the 70's, but was definitely weird or inspired, depending on your viewpoint. Look up his self-portraits, or if you can find it, his portrait of Hitler. Then there are his writings... Anyway, just a random thought...

Is there any objective evidence to support this view?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Unfortunately “I’m curious if other people feel like I do” is a [thing not to ask](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). I've edited the question

Comment: In the linked Q&A, there are three or four sources that back up "going spare" means "get angry" in British English. However, (in the original version of the question) it seems like you're asking for weaker evidence (anecdotes or personal opinions). What evidence *are* you looking for?